# Printing all items of an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I know this is a very basic question, but I have searched and have not found a suitable answer for my problem. I have an ArrayList of Objects which is populated from a Scanner. When I try to print out all the elements in the list, I only get the last element repeated as many times as objects in the list.

First the Object class:

```
public class Colors {
    String name;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name.toString();
    }
}
```

Now the main class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Vec { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Colors col= new Colors();
    List <Colors> l = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean flag = true;

    while(flag == true){
       System.out.println("Type in name of color");
       Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
       col.name = kb.next();
       l.add(col);

       for (int j= 0; j<l.size();j++) {
           Object g = (Object)l.get(j);
           System.out.println("Name of color: "+g);
       }
     }
   }
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring objects in Java by using the `new` keyword. You are only declaring one instance of `Colors`, then changing its name over and over again. Then adding that same `Colors` to the list over and over. What you need to do is to change where you are declaring your `Colors`, that can be done inside the `while` statement.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vec
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List <Colors> l = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean flag = true;

        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);

        while (flag) {
            System.out.println("Type in name of color");

            Colors col = new Colors ();
            col.name = kb.next();
            l.add(col);

            for (int j = 0; j<l.size();j++) {
                Object g = (Object)l.get(j);
                System.out.println("Name of color: "+g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The difference here is that `col` is now re-declared in the local scope of of your `while` statement.

---

**Small notes, these are off-topic and aimed at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than answering the question.**

---

`while (flag == true)`, no need to compare against `true`. You also do not need to creaste a new `Scanner` all the time.

---

I suggest to use better names for your variables. `l`, `col`, `kb`, `flag` could basically be anything.

Some **recommendations** (they are just that, recommendations):

- l, is your list, containing many `Colors`, now `Colors` is misleading as well, as it is only one color, I recommend to change the class name to `Color` and the list `l` to `colors`.
- col, is fine.
- kb, use `scanner` instead.
- flag, of what? Instead use `running`, `playing`, `on`.

---

Another addition is that since you know what your `l` stores you can use a `for` each instead.

```
            for (Colors c : l) {
                System.out.println("Name of color: " + c);
            }
```

Comment: I think it is good to mention that op is dealing with scope issue

Comment: I did state it "The difference here is that col is now re-declared in the local scope of of your while statement." However I can rephrase it a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: Emz, i will keep in mind your suggestions. Thank you for your quick and effective reply. The problem was then with the scope issue...